# Fluid flexbox grid with fixed column widths

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a container set up via flexbox. I'd like to equally distribute each of the tiles inside the container but keep them at a fixed width of 220px.

I've come close using `flex-grow` and setting a `min-width: 220px`, but it obviously has computationally resized the tiles in order to fill the container.

I've also set up some media queries so that the tiles stack on certain breakpoints.

With my current styling is it possible to keep these tiles at 220px without them stretching? Can this be done via flexbox? Is there an alternative that's just as good as flexbox?

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jo58t7h/1)**

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 2000px;
}
.tiles {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 15px 30px 15px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0;
  height: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 850px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 2040px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1750px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1790px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1500px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1540px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1250px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1290px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1000px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 750px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 790px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you also need the *tiles* to be always in the center?

Comment: have you tried simply setting the `width` property of your `.tiles`?

Comment: See this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ud9fkw5/4/), I guess you don't need those media queries.

Comment: @Pangloss Sorry I seemed to misworded my pervious comment. I basically wanted the grid to work as so (without using `float`: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/EBncj/6/. Via: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21245751/3046413

Comment: Got you! OK see this post - http://stackoverflow.com/q/33192745/483779 I actually offered a bounty of 200 rep for it a while ago, still no better solutions so far, even with flexbox.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for referring me to this solution. I have one question though: Is it possible for the `.inner` div to align left, span the width of its parent (100%) and function in the same manner as before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'd like to equally distribute each of the tiles inside the container
>   but keep them at a fixed width of 220px.
>
> With my current styling is it possible to keep these tiles at 220px
>   without them stretching?
>
> Can this be done via flexbox?

Yes, and yes.

Instead of using `flex-grow` and `min-width` on the tiles, use the `flex` property.

So, instead of:

```
.tiles {
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 220px;
}
```

Try this:

```
.tiles {
    flex: 0 0 220px; /* don't grow, don't shrink, stay at 220px width */
}
```

The `flex` property is shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis`.

The `flex-grow` property controls how a flex item will grow relative to other flex items in the container when extra space is distributed. By setting the value to `0`, it doesn't grow at all from the initial main size (defined by `flex-basis`).

The `flex-shrink` property controls how a flex item will shrink relative to other flex items when they overflow the container. By setting the value to `0`, it doesn't shrink at all from the initial main size (defined by `flex-basis`).

The `flex-basis` property sets the initial main size of a flex item.

---

> I've also setup some media queries so that the tiles stack on certain breakpoints.

By using the `flex` property, as specified above, along with `flex-wrap`, which you already have in your code, you may not need media queries. Consider scrapping them.

---

At this point, you may have your layout: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4jo58t7h/2/)

OR

You may be at a common sticking point: *When flex items wrap, the container does not recalculate its width to shrink-wrap the fewer columns, resulting in a [large area of whitespace on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811002/3597276).*

For more details and a possible workaround see my answer here: [**Flexbox Limitation & Challenge**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811002/3597276)

---

**UPDATE**

After a few clarifications and revisions were made in the comments, the solution was found:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="content">
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
            ...
            ...
            ...
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
*
{
    margin:0;padding:0;
}

#content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.box {
    flex: 0 0 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
}

@media (min-width: 200px) {
  #content {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  #content {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  #content {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #content {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #content {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  #content {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #content {
    width: 800px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  #content {
    width: 900px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  #content {
    width: 1000px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  #content {
    width: 1100px;
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EBncj/15/)

Answer (score 1):

So flexbox has the ability to grow and shrink, which you can turn off (you can read a little more about that [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), I find this a nice, quick flexbox guide). Shorthand for defining `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` all at once is `flex: 0 0 auto`, the zeros meaning that the box won't grow or shrink, but remain the same size you defined previously. I modified your jsfiddle to show how it works:

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3ud9fkw5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments on Michael_B answer, I believe that what is missing is a justify-content: center ...

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 2000px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tiles {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 15px 30px 15px;
  flex: 0 0 220px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 220px;
}

.filler {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: 0 15px 0px 15px;
  flex: 0 0 220px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="tiles"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
  <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem I'm finding with `justify-content` is that the odd remaining tiles with center (as they should) vs. aligning left.

Comment: Adding extra elements to the HTML would be ok ?

Comment: Well..the tiles will be generated dynamically so I won't be able to determine how many/few there are in the container.

Comment: You don't need to. You only need to add a number high enough for the worst case. See the example with 10 fillers