# How do I center left-floated elements?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a container of various width, and various number of boxes float inside it. All the boxes have same `width` and `height`.

This is a demonstration.
https://jsfiddle.net/kghvmjb6/1/

I am looking for pure CSS solution if possible. Otherwise pure javascript (no jQuery) and CSS solutions are fine.

This example works fine with one line of floating boxes but fail with multiple lines, which is not I want.
https://codepen.io/alexandredees/pen/ojaFr

Comment: This is possible with pure CSS - but you have to use a bunch of media queries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21245751/703717

Comment: @Danield Thanks! Finally something work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `float` `left`, use `display` `inline-block` and in the parent `div` add `text-align` `center`, that will center the boxes in the `container`

[Modified Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/kghvmjb6/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="">
   <div class="box">1</div>
   <div class="box">2</div>
   <div class="box">3</div>
   <div class="box">4</div>
   <div class="box">5</div>
   <div class="box">6</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
   border: 1px solid red;
   width: 480px; text-align:center;
 }

  .container.wider {
    width: 530px;
  }

 .box {
   float: none;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   margin: 10px;
   background-color: #ddd;
   display:inline-block;
   }
```

Comment: This will not work as I want. If I have total 6 boxes with 4 boxes in line 1 and 2 boxes in line 2, I want box 5 and 6 place right under box 1 and 2

Comment: Use float left and set margin from left right to adjust this.

Comment: How do I set correct margins? The width of the container is unknown.